# Changing theme color from grey to blue

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material, mean-stack

I am trying to change the default *GREY color of the placeholder in md-input-container to Material Blue color*. I have tried to change the default theme like mentioned in the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/api/service/$mdThemingProvider) and I have tried making my own theme to theme a specific view/ui item. However none of the below code works to modify the color of the md-input-container placeholder. What am I missing?

```
mainApp.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('alt')
        .backgroundPalette('blue-grey')
        .primaryPalette('orange')
        .accentPalette('green');
});

<md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30" md-theme="alt">
    <input required type="text" placeholder="Week"
           />

    <div ng-messages="$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: A codepen or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't found an official way to do this.

You can either use the selector (note that the theme name is part of it):

```
md-input-container.md-alt-theme label,
md-input-container.md-alt-theme .md-placeholder {
  color: rgb(96, 125, 139);
}
```

Or you can modify the `foregroundPalette`, seems the input label uses the third one:

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('alt').foregroundPalette[3] = 'rgb(96, 125, 139)';
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Where did you find the foregroundPallete? Couldn't find it docs unless you unearthed it from source code.

Comment: Sadly didn't find it documented. Found it in the source code and mentioned in an issue on Github.